# How to Get JSON Data From Postman to Rest Controller

Tags: json, web-services, spring-mvc, postman

I have some questions on rest, pls help.

Q 1.)

I am working on Spring MVC and already configured dispatcher servlet to take incoming request, but now I am using some restfull web services also in that project, so is there any thing to change in web.xml file?

Q. 2) 
How to hit rest controller from Postman tool by passing JSON data inside body, using put request?.

Thanks, 
Shashank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do same as shown in bellow Images it definitely works don't forget to like 
 Step 1
[image]
Just select the PUT method in drop-down and Pass the Token do same as there in Image

Step 2

[image: Select the Body and raw radio buttons and select the JsonApplication in dropdwon as shown in Image]